# JQUERY - PHP - MySQL - Result array addition, more info added

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I accidentally deleted my last post, so here it is again:

I have a small warehouse with several parts, I'm in the process of coding a jquery, php, mysql part look up tool, I have some parts that come as a kit which have additional part numbers within them.

The current query needs a column in the mysql table which says something like HasChild, if this says "yes" then it will show additional data from the result array. How can I add this to my current result loop?

Here is the code that I am working with currently:

```
<?php

$dbhost = "dbhost";
$dbname = "dbname";
$dbuser = "dbuser";
$dbpass = "dbpass";


global $part_lookup_tool_db;

$part_lookup_tool_db = new mysqli();
$part_lookup_tool_db->connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$part_lookup_tool_db->set_charset("utf8");


if ($part_lookup_tool_db->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $part_lookup_tool_db->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$html = '';
$html .= '<li class="result">';
$html .= '<h1 class="btn2"><center> oemprojString</center></h1>';
$html .= '<h2><b>Part Number: functionString</b></h2>';
$html .= '<h4><b>Stock Item Description:</b> nameString</h4>';
$html .= '<h4><b>Stock Type:</b> stocktypeString</h4>';
$html .= '<h4><b>Vendor:</b> vendorString</h4>';
$html .= '</br>';
$html .= '<a target="_blank" href="imageString">';
$html .= '<center><img class="imn" src="imageString" width="50%" height="50%"></center></a>';
$html .= '</br>';
$html .= '<h4><b>Notes:</b> notesString</h4>';
$html .= '</li>';


$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
$search_string = $part_lookup_tool_db->real_escape_string($search_string);


if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM search WHERE function LIKE "%' . $search_string . '%" OR name LIKE "%' . $search_string . '%"';


    $result = $part_lookup_tool_db->query($query);
    while ($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $result_array[] = $results;
    }

    if (isset($result_array)) {
        foreach ($result_array as $result) {


            $display_function = preg_replace("/" . $search_string . "/i", "<b class='highlight'>" . $search_string . "</b>", $result['function']);
            $display_name = preg_replace("/" . $search_string . "/i", "<b class='highlight'>" . $search_string . "</b>", $result['name']);
            $display_image = preg_replace("/" . $search_string . "/i", "" . $search_string . "", $result['image']);
            $display_stocktype = preg_replace("/" . $search_string . "/i", "<b class='highlight'>" . $search_string . "</b>", $result['stocktype']);
            $display_vendor = preg_replace("/" . $search_string . "/i", "<b class='highlight'>" . $search_string . "</b>", $result['vendor']);
            $display_notes = preg_replace("/" . $search_string . "/i", "<b class='highlight'>" . $search_string . "</b>", $result['notes']);
            $display_oemproj = preg_replace("/" . $search_string . "/i", "<b class='highlight'>" . $search_string . "</b>", $result['oemproj']);


            $output = str_replace('nameString', $display_name, $html);
            $output = str_replace('functionString', $display_function, $output);
            $output = str_replace('imageString', $display_image, $output);
            $output = str_replace('stocktypeString', $display_stocktype, $output);
            $output = str_replace('vendorString', $display_vendor, $output);
            $output = str_replace('notesString', $display_notes, $output);
            $output = str_replace('oemprojString', $display_oemproj, $output);

            echo($output);
        }
    } else {

        $output = str_replace('nameString', '<font color="red">No Data Found.</font>', $output);
        $output = str_replace('functionString', '<font color="red">No Data Found.</font>', $output);
        $output = str_replace('imageString', 'http://i.imgur.com/default.png', $output);
        $output = str_replace('stocktypeString', '<font color="red">No Data Found.</font>', $output);
        $output = str_replace('vendorString', '<font color="red">No Data Found.</font>', $output);
        $output = str_replace('notesString', '<font color="red">No Data Found.</font>', $output);
        $output = str_replace('oemprojString', '<font color="red">No Data Found.</font>', $output);

        echo($output);
    }
}
?>
```

I've done some research and I think this is what I need to add, but I just can't figure out where:

```
if (isset($result_array)) {
    foreach ($result_array as $result) {

        if ($result['HasChildren'] == "yes") {

            echo $result['ChildParts'];
        } elseif ($result['HasChildren'] == "no") {

            echo $result['nochildren'];
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks again to anyone that helps me out, I really appreciate all the help I can get.

Here is the [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5790f4/1) to SQLfiddle.com  <-- Use this SQLfiddle

I would like this to be in PHP or whatever you all think would work best with the code I have provided. --Thanks again.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would like the final output to look?

Comment: @PatrickQ well basically I want to show anything all results that match the end-users search string, but if it does have children parts to also show addition information for that search result, let me know if you don't get what I mean.. I'll try to setup an example you can play with online.

Comment: "...show addition information for that search result…" What information? Show it how? etc. At first glance, I'd say that you want to restructure your tables such that you have a `kits` table with `kitPartID`, `childPartID`, and `quantity` columns. Or something along those lines.

Comment: @PatrickQ That is correct, I have already restructured my tables, and am working on a mock-up for you which I'll also make something simple in Photoshop for you to see the results.

Comment: @PatrickQ -- Had a long weekend with family I'll have everything ready for you by EOD tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this done using the following code below, thank you all for the help!

```
if (strlen($search_string) >= 3 && $search_string !== ' ') {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM search WHERE function LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR name LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR stocktype LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR vendor LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR notes LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR oemproj LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"';


    $result = $imn_tool_db->query($query);
    while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $result_array[] = $results;
    }

    if (isset($result_array)) {
        foreach ($result_array as $result) {


            $display_function = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['function']);
            $display_name = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['name']);
            $display_image = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "".$search_string."", $result['image']);
            $display_stocktype = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['stocktype']);
            $display_vendor = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['vendor']);
            $display_notes = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['notes']);
            $display_oemproj = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['oemproj']);


            $output = str_replace('nameString', $display_name, $html);
            $output = str_replace('functionString', $display_function, $output);
            $output = str_replace('imageString', $display_image, $output);
            $output = str_replace('stocktypeString', $display_stocktype, $output);
            $output = str_replace('vendorString', $display_vendor, $output);
            $output = str_replace('notesString', $display_notes, $output);
            $output = str_replace('oemprojString', $display_oemproj, $output);

            echo($output);
        }
    }else{

        // Format No Results Output
        $output = str_replace('nameString', '<font color="red">No Data Found.</font>', $html);
        $output = str_replace('functionString', '<font color="red">No Data Found.</font>', $output);
        $output = str_replace('imageString', 'http://i.imgur.com/default.png', $output);
        $output = str_replace('stocktypeString', '<font color="red">No Data Found.</font>', $output);
        $output = str_replace('vendorString', '<font color="red">No Data Found.</font>', $output);
        $output = str_replace('notesString', '<font color="red">No Data Found.</font>', $output);
        $output = str_replace('oemprojString', '<font color="red">No Data Found.</font>', $output);

        echo($output);
    }

    if (isset($result_array)) {
        foreach ($result_array as $result) {

                if($result['hasChildren']=="yes") { ?>
                           <center>
                           <table class='kitTable' width='98%' border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' bordercolor='556587'>
                              <tr>
                                <td width='70%' class='kitHeading'><?php echo $result['kitHeading'];?></td>
                                <td width='15%' class='kitHeading'><?php echo $result['partHeading'];?></td>
                                <td width='15%' class='kitHeading'><?php echo $result['qtyHeading'];?></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $result['kitPart1'];?></td>
                                <td class='trCenter'><?php echo $result['childPart1'];?></td>
                                <td class='trCenter'><?php echo $result['childPartQTY1'];?></td>
                              </tr> <?php

                        if($result['kitPart2']=== NULL) { ?>
                              <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $result['kitPart2'];?></td>
                                <td class='trCenter'><?php echo $result['childPart2'];?></td>
                                <td class='trCenter'><?php echo $result['childPartQTY2'];?></td>
                              </tr>
                             <?php }

                            ?>  
                            </table>
                            </center>
                            <?php
                    }

                    elseif($result['hasChildren']=="no") {
                        echo "";
                    }               
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd use PDO. PDO is the same as mysqli was prior to mysql. In short: it's 'just' another MySQL Adapter for PHP (PDO stands for PHP Data Objects).

If using PDO, this is most likely want you'll want to do:

**STEP 1 -- Open your connection**

To open a connection in PDO, all you have to do is:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;port=xxxx;dbname=xxx', 'username', 'password');
```

**STEP 2 -- Create your query**

To gather data from your database, you have to know what you're looking for. That's what the query is for. Let's say we want to select all columns from the 'Products' table, we will do the following:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products";
```

Ofcourse, these queries can become more difficult when using JOINS and all of those other neat MySQL features, but let's keep it simple for now.

**STEP 3 -- Prepare your query**

Before executing your query, prepare it:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
```

This way your query is ready to launch, so let's execute your query:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

If all went well, we can continue to step 4.

**STEP 4 -- Retrieve your data**

Perhaps the most important step (atleast, if you use databases and want to retrieve data), is to retrieve data (Duh...). PDO (and mysqli) have an easy way of looping through a ResultSet:

```
while($rs = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    //Do something with your data
}
```

This may go a bit fast, but what this does is make a while loop until all elements in $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) have been looped through. I am using PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, because it enables us to use

```
$column1Value = $rs['column1'];
```

If that column exists ofcourse.

Enough chit-chat about how it should work, let's get into YOUR problem.

This should be the code for your problem (although it's not tested):

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=xxxxx;port=xxxx;dbname=xxxx', 'username', 'password');
$query = "SELECT * FROM yourTable";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

while ($rs = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $hasChildren = $rs['hasChildren'];
    if ($hasChildren === 'yes') {
        //Continue getting data from children
    } else {
        //Stop the function?
    }
}
```

I might be missing some points, but this might get you started I think.

Comment: This does not at all answer the user's question. While the point of using PDO is valid, it belongs as a comment.